# Could ethereum be used to bypass Internet censorship?

Tags: dapp-development

AFAIK ethereum is a decentralized platform run programs on computers all over the world, so is it possible to write a program to help bypass Internet censorship? for example, if I'm in China, I can connect to a computer in USA as a proxy to visit some blocked websites?

Comment: Are you asking if someone could write a proxy server or something similar in Ethereum? Or do you mean is it possible to write a Dapp that is resistant to censorship?

Comment: @lungj i'd like to know if it's possible or if there's already some projects doing this

Comment: There's the Mysterium team (https://mysterium.network/) working on a decentralized VPN.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not.

Blockchains (without dedicated cryptography like zero-knowledge proofs) provide no privacy. Your node connects to blockchains via specific ports, which can be blocked by the ISP. Using Tor may come to mind, but research showed that [using Bitcoin over Tor is not as secure as it seems](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.6079) (Ethereum is not that much different from the networking perspective). And speaking of China, they [use sophisticated DPI (deep packet inspection) techniques](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.04044) to detect and block traffic to blacklisted websites.

IMO, the only thing blockchains can help for circumventing censorship is by providing an anonymous payment mechanism for VPN providers / [Tor relays](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/1011) / etc.